# Handle client-side cancellation in gRPC python asyncio?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, grpc, grpc-python

Question first, context below. How can I perform some server-side action (eg, cleanup) based on a cancellation of an RPC from the client *with an async gRPC python server*?

In my microservice, I have an `asyncio` gRPC server whose main RPCs are bidirectional streams.

On the client side (which is also using asyncio), when I cancel something, it raises an `asyncio.CancelledError` which is caught and not reraised by the `grpc` core:

https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/python/grpcio/grpc/_cython/_cygrpc/aio/server.pyx.pxi#L679

```
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        _LOGGER.debug('RPC cancelled for servicer method [%s]', _decode(rpc_state.method()))
```

So I cannot rely on catching the `asyncio.CancelledError` in my own code, because it's caught beforehand and not reraised.

The shared context is supposed to contain information as to whether the RPC was canceled on the client side, by calling `.cancel()` from the RPC call and being able to see if it was canceled by calling `.cancelled()`:

https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/grpc_asyncio.html#shared-context

> abstract cancel()
>
> ```
> Cancels the RPC.
>
> Idempotent and has no effect if the RPC has already terminated.
>
> Returns
>
>     A bool indicates if the cancellation is performed or not.
> Return type
>
>     bool
> ```
>
> abstract cancelled()
>
> ```
> Return True if the RPC is cancelled.
>
> The RPC is cancelled when the cancellation was requested with cancel().
>
> Returns
>
>     A bool indicates whether the RPC is cancelled or not.
> Return type
>
>     bool
> ```

However, this shared context is not attached to the `context` variable given to the RPC on the server side by the gRPC generated code. (I cannot run `context.cancelled()` or `context.add_done_callback`; they're not present)

So, again, the question: How can I perform some server-side action (eg, cleanup) based on a cancellation of an RPC from the client *with an async gRPC python server*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

thanks for the post. We are aware of this issue, and adding support for those two methods is on our roadmap.

For a short term solution, you can use try-catch and decorators. The client-side-cancellation is observed as an `asyncio.CancelledError` in method handler. Here is a modified [helloworld example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/examples/python/helloworld):

Server code:

```
class Greeter(helloworld_pb2_grpc.GreeterServicer):

    async def SayHello(
            self, request: helloworld_pb2.HelloRequest,
            context: grpc.aio.ServicerContext) -> helloworld_pb2.HelloReply:
        try:
            await asyncio.sleep(4)
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            print('RPC cancelled')
            raise
        return helloworld_pb2.HelloReply(message='Hello, %s!' % request.name)
```

Client code:

```
async def run() -> None:
    async with grpc.aio.insecure_channel('localhost:50051') as channel:
        stub = helloworld_pb2_grpc.GreeterStub(channel)
        call = stub.SayHello(helloworld_pb2.HelloRequest(name='you'))
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        call.cancel()
        print(await call.code())
```